# Create infinite array of arrays in java

Tags: java

I wanted to create an array of dynamic types as in javascript. I wanted to convert
below code of javascript into java.

```
const a = [1, [2, 3, [4, 5,[6, 7]....]]]
```

The above array will have nested array for every 2 elements and depth can be infinite. It is dynamic.

Is there a way to create such array in java? As I found we need to declare before hand the nested arrays as below

```
List<List<Integer>>
```

But in above code, I can only use 2 nested list with integers that too I can't use combination of integers and List inside 1st list. If I want to add another list inside second list I need to declare as

```
List<List<List<Integer>>>
```

So I need a way to solve this problem

Comment: You could try `List<Object>` which can take objects of any type.

Comment: _Why_ do you want this data structure? What is it _for_?

Comment: XY Problem. If you suggest what business requirement your trying to solve we can probably provide you with a simpler solution.

Comment: How is that array dynamic, it looks like a hard coded structure to me? I am no JavaScript developer so please explain if I am wrong.

Comment: The closest you'll get is `final var a = List.of(1, List.of(2, 3, List.of(4, 5, List.of(6, 7)....)))` — but *why*?

Comment: This is one of the interview question that was asked in my previous interview.

Comment: @OmarAbdelBari @JoakimDanielson@MCEmperor Let me explain the question first to get more context.

He asked to write a program that accepts an array which could of above format.
Few inputs: 
`[1, 3, [4, 8]]
AND 
[2, [9, [10, 11], 12], 20]`

I need to flatten the array into single array.

He mentioned, that could be of any level of depth. So to accept that kind of dynamic array, I would need to first declare my variable. So I was stuck.

Comment: This sounds a little different to what you are trying to do. Since you will have to keep track of the brackets you get from command line you would not have to do a chain of List.Of in one line anyway. IE it's incremental.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to create such array in java?

Yes and no. Java is a strongly typed language. With that said, every object in Java inherits from the built-in class `Object`. So you could do something like

```java
Object[] array = new Object[]{1, new Object[]{2, new Object[]{3, /* ... */}}};
```

Although, using such a construct would be a real pain. You'll need to type-cast values before you can use them as their sourced type again.

```java
Integer a = (Integer) array[0];
Object[] b = (Object[]) array[1];
```

You can achieve dynamic sizing using `List<Object>`.